# CSS - background-color element issue - circle shows as oval

Tags: html, css

I've been strugling to get my background circle element round.

I've got a label with X as for the closing button.

I'm putting background color behind the X, so I'd like to create a circle behind the X.

I just can't get the circle to be a round circle, it is showing as oval.

```css
.label {
  padding: 0 !important;
  list-style: none !important;
}

.label__choice {
  display: inline !important;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.label__choice__remove {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  color: #2ecc71 !important;
  font-weight: 900;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="label">
  <li class="label__choice">
    <span class="label__choice__remove">×</span> Lessons
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmagL4p1/1/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `span` is an inline element. Not all CSS properties can be applied on inline elements. Make it `inline-block` or set some other display and it will work.

Comment: You were faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add :

```
display: inline-block;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-align: center;
```

inside `.label__choice__remove`

Main problem was that span is `inline` element, thus width/height won't work`

Here's updated snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/mmagL4p1/2/

Answer (score 1):

A `<span>` is an inline element, which width is defined by it's content and can't be defined with CSS.

So you need it to act as a inline-block, so add `display: inline-block` to your CSS.
See my code, and note that I made some more tweaks to make ik look better.

```css
.label {
  padding: 0 !important;
  list-style: none !important;
}

.label__choice {
  display: inline !important;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.label__choice__remove {
  display: inline-block; /* <----------------- add this */
  text-align: center;/* <- for better looks */
  vertical-align: middle;/* <- for better looks */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #2ecc71 !important;
  font-weight: 900;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="label">
  <li class="label__choice">
    <span class="label__choice__remove">&times;</span> Lessons
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome, many thanks, the X is still showing a little out of the circle. How can I fix it so it's right at the middle, and the whole circle in the middle of the text?

Comment: That's because the `x` takes more space than the 15px; So increase height and width to for example 20px, and remove the padding (see the update)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.label { 
padding: 0 !important;
list-style: none !important;
}

.label__choice {
display: inline !important;
padding: 10px;
margin: 4px;
color: #fff !important;
background-color: #2ecc71;
border: none;
border-radius: 3px;
}

.label__choice__remove {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0px 6px 2px 6px;
    color: #2ecc71 !important;
    font-weight: 900;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="label">
  <li class="label__choice">
    <span class="label__choice__remove">×</span>
    Lessons
  </li>
</ul>
```